# How to create source maps dynamically with grunt-closurecompiler

Tags: gruntjs, google-closure-compiler

I can't get it to work. `name_of_current_file` needs to somehow be replaced with name of the current file being processed. It seems to me like the options property is only evaluated once and reused for each file.

```
    closurecompiler: {
        dev: {
            files:[{
                expand: true,
                flatten: true,
                cwd: 'www',
                src: ['src/js/*.js', '!src/js/*.min.js'],
                dest: 'www/build/js/',
                ext: '.min.js',
            }],
            options: {
                // Any options supported by Closure Compiler, for example:
                "compilation_level": "ADVANCED_OPTIMIZATIONS",
                "create_source_map": name_of_current_file+'.map',

                // Plus a simultaneous processes limit
                "max_processes": 4,
            }
        },
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the replacement variable `%outname%` in your source map naming.

```
"create_source_map": '%outname%.map'
```

Also, make sure you are using the [officially supported Grunt Plugin](https://github.com/google/closure-compiler-npm#using-the-grunt-task).

Comment: Worked like a charm! How come good stuff like this `%outname%` is not in the docs?